# is there any software that let me schedule SNMPWALK on device on specific intervals?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, monitoring, snmp, monitor, job-scheduling

I need to know if there is any program that let me schedule SNMP monitoring based on MIB files on spesific period of times without user intervention.
also I need to be able to recieve traps from the device. the monitored device is already configured with all requierd SNMP configuration.

my Administration machine is Windows and my monitored device is Linux.

this is what I want to be able to do with the software in more details:

1. load my company MIB files (standard company MIB and also company trap MIB) into the software.
2. perform SNMP GET, GET_NEXT and SNMPWALK
3. recieve traps from the device to the software.
4. most important: with the software, I need to be able to schedule automation of SNMPWALK\SNMP_GET\SNMP_GET_NEXT on the device with my company MIBS without user intervention: 
   for example - perform SNMPWALK on the device every sunday at 08:00 (and also  of-course monitor for traps alerts regulary).

is there any software that does that?

Answer (score 1):

There are many SNMP products on the market. The industry standard enterprise-grade product for SNMP traps handling on Windows platform is **NetDecision TrapVision**. Find out more at: http://www.netmechanica.com/products/?prod_id=1003 . It does many things:

- Fully supports SNMPv1, SNMPv2C, SNMPv3 (USM and VACM)
- Ultra high performance (thousands traps per minute)
- Resolves incoming SNMP traps based on MIB definitions (You can load any MIB files both standard and enterprise specific)
- You can filter out SNMP traps
- You can write incoming traps to DB or log file
- You can configure rules (trap handlers) to execute custom actions on the reception of a SNMP trap like email, sms, etc
- You can assign severity to a trap based on rules
- You can acknowledge and clear SNMP traps via GUI.
- You can assign troubleshooting information to a particular trap
- SNMP traps are displayed in modern GUI. You can manage SNMP notifications as easy as emails in MS Outlook.
- etc

As for SNMPWALK and automatic SNMP polling there is a product called **Performance Vision**. Find more info at: http://netmechanica.com/products/?prod_id=1022

[image: NetDecision TrapVision]